How to get the number of observations per table for a library without using sashelp.vtable
let me first point out that I am new to SAS.
I have a library with a certain amount of data sets in it.
This library is not SAS native but is connected to SAS Server via an ODBC driver. Let's call this library extlib.
I want to get an output data set containing the number of observations for each data set in the extlib library. In other words an output that looks like this:



libname
memname
nobs




extlib
tabA
1000


extlib
tabB
2000


extlib
tabC
0


extlib
tabD
1500



I learnt that for 'normal' libraries ie libraries hosted in a SAS DBMS, obtaining such table is rather easy, as you can find it in sashelp.vtable if you run something like this:
DATA want;
SET sashelp.vtable (WHERE=(libname="EXTLIB") KEEP=libname memname nobs);
RUN;

The problem is when I run this specifically filtering on extlib I get this result:



libname
memname
nobs




extlib
tabA
.


extlib
tabB
.


extlib
tabC
.


extlib
tabD
.



while other data sets in other libraries do have a value in for nobs in sashelp.vtable.
I suspect the fact the library comes from a foreign source is at stake in this issue.
When I run:
PROC SQL;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nobs FROM extlib.tabA;
QUIT;

I get my info for a specific table.
The issue is I have a huge amount of tables in this database and I can access them by SAS only,
so my question is: how to obtain this result for every data set in the library?

Do you know what system you're connection to? Often many databases have metadata tables simliar to vtable and you can connect to those to get the information through sql pass thru.

The easiest way is to research how to do the equivalent metadata query in the database language of the system where they do live.  So then you could just call that code:
 proc sql;
   connect using EXTLIB;
   create table want as select * from connection to EXTLIB
      (... code that works in the foreign database ... )
   ;
 quit;

Otherwise you will need actually ask SAS to COUNT how many observations there are and then update the NOBS column with the right answer.  So perhaps with a macro like this.
%macro contents(libref,out=contents);
%local libname memname ds ;
proc sql noprint;
 create table &out as
  select
     t.LIBNAME as LIBNAME label='Library reference'
    ,t.memname as MEMNAME label='Dataset name'
    ,t.MEMTYPE as MEMTYPE label='Dataset type'
    ,t.MODATE as MODATE label='Last mod datetime'
    ,t.nlobs as NOBS label='Number of observations'
    ,t.NVAR as NVAR label='Number of variables'
    ,t.OBSLEN as OBSLEN label='Observation length'
    ,t.memlabel as MEMLABEL label='Dataset label'
  from dictionary.tables t 
  where t.libname = "%upcase(&libref)"
  order by 1,2
  ;

%do %while(&sqlobs);
  select libname,memname,catx('.',libname,nliteral(memname))
    into :libname trimmed, :memname trimmed, :ds
    from &out where missing(nobs)
  ;
  %if (&sqlobs) %then %do;
  update &out set nobs = (select count(*) from &ds)
    where libname="&libname" and memname="&memname"
  ;
  %end;
%end;

quit;

%mend;

Let's conduct a test:
proc datasets nolist lib=work memtype=data kill;
run;
data x; do i=1 to 5; output; end; run;
data v/view=v; set x; where i<3 ; run;

option mprint;
%contents(work);

proc print;
run;

Result
OBS    LIBNAME    MEMNAME    MEMTYPE         MODATE         NOBS    NVAR    OBSLEN    MEMLABEL

 1      WORK         V        VIEW      19JUN24:11:40:39      2       1        8
 2      WORK         X        DATA      19JUN24:11:40:39      5       1        8

NOTE the use of the NLOBS variable from DICTIONARY.TABLES so that any deleted observations from a dataset are not counted.

Found a "solution" using Macro and CALL execute()
DATA rowCount; *creating an empty table to host row count info;
ATTRIB
    tabName length=$255 format=$255. informat=$255.
    nRows length=8 format=20. informat=20.;
STOP;
RUN;

/* 
   Macro-Function linking that inserts for each table from the 'extlib' library
   the name of this table and the count of rows through a PROC SQL
 */
%MACRO countRows(tableName);
    PROC SQL;
        INSERT INTO rowCount
        SELECT "&tableName." AS tabName, COUNT(*) AS nRows
        FROM EXTLIB.&tableName.;
    QUIT;
%MEND countRows;

/* Will execute countRows for every values of the 'memname' column */
DATA _NULL_;
    SET sashelp.vtable (WHERE=(libname="EXTLIB"));
    CALL execute('%countRows('||memname||');');
RUN;

More of a workaround but it solved my problem.

No need to make the macro if you don't already have it.  Just use data step code to generate the SQL code to pass to CALL EXECUTE.
